# In Facebook graph API how to find which all of your friends like a particular page with detail info?

Tags: database, facebook, api

I'm trying to figure out how to find how many of my friends "like" a particular page 
and friends' detailed information such as `id`, `name`, and `picture`.

For example: for a given page ID, how can I look up how many of my friends have already liked the same page for the `ID`?

I just know that when I use this `FQL` ==>

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 114719705207104 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

I only got a list of a friends' `uid`s.

But I'd like to get friend list with `name`, `id`, `picture`, and `URL`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just add another **IN** to the query

```
SELECT uid, pic, name, username FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 114719705207104 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))
```

The UID is the user id you want.

The URL for the user is equal to www.facebook.com/UID or www.facebook.com/USERNAME
Since not every user has a username I advise you to use the first option with the UID.

You have many ways of retrieving the user pic, with the uid you can use the graph api to fetch the pic in various sizes, doing this

https://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture or https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/picture

Then adding some get parameters you can configure the size of the pic. You can read more about that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

If you want to keep using FQL for selecting the pic, you have many fields in the User table that return different sizes. You can read more about the user table [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) and see the available fields for the pic

Comment: if this answer solved your problem just mark it as correct, for future reference

Comment: has facebook dis-allowed this in the 2.0 api?  Seems they don't allow you to see which pages the user's friends like...  ?

Comment: You are right, also FQL is deprecated in the 2.1 API version